# Proving $\lnot \lnot (\psi \lor \lnot \psi)$ is a theorem of intuitionistic propositional logic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, intuitionistic-logic, kripke-models

Here, $\psi$ is some arbitrary formula.

The proof I've come up with is as follows.

Assume $\lnot \lnot (\psi \lor \lnot \psi)$ is not a theorem of IPL, which means there exists some Kripke model where

$$\exists w: w \not\models \lnot \lnot (\psi \lor \lnot \psi),$$

which, by definition of negation being truthful in Kripke models, is equivalent to

$$\exists w: \exists u \geq w: u \models \lnot (\psi \lor \lnot \psi).$$

This, again by definition of negation truthfulness, implies for this $u$ that

$$\forall v \geq u : v \not \models \psi \lor \lnot \psi.$$

By definition of truthfulness of $\lor$ in Kripke models, this, in turn, implies

$$\forall v \geq u : v \not \models \psi, v \not \models \lnot \psi.$$

But if $\forall v \geq u : v \not \models \psi$, then $u \models \lnot\psi$, which contradicts $\forall v \geq u : v \not \models \lnot \psi$.

Hence, the original assumption is false, and $\lnot \lnot (\psi \lor \lnot \psi)$ is a theorem of IPL.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Or you could use syntax instead of semantics.

Comment: I haven't got that far in my self-studies yet.

Comment: I find syntax easier than semantics, to be frank.

Comment: Just curious, how would you use syntax in this case?

Comment: Which style of proof do you use?

Comment: I don't have much experience with any, so whatever you find most straightforward. I'll look any missing pieces up (or I'll ask more questions :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $\lnot \lnot (P \lor \lnot P)$, assume $\lnot (P \lor \lnot P)$ and show that it leads to a contradiction.

Under that assumption, you can show both $\lnot P$ holds by contradiction as well as $\lnot \lnot P$ holds, which is the desired contradiction.  In long form:

$$
\begin{array} {rl}
% Markup
\begin{array} {r}
\begin{array} {r|}
\text{Assumption } \\ \hline
\begin{array} {r|} 
\text{Assumption } \\ \hline
\text{Or Intro } \\
\text{Contradiction } \\
\end{array} \\
\text{Negation Intro } \\
\begin{array} {r|} 
\text{Assumption } \\ \hline
\text{Or Intro } \\
\text{Contradiction } \\
\end{array} \\
\text{Negation Intro } \\
\text{Contradiction } \\
\end{array} \\
\text{Negation Intro }
\end{array} & 
% Proof
\begin{array} {l}
\begin{array} {|l}
\lnot (P \lor \lnot P) \\ \hline
\begin{array} {|l} 
P \\ \hline
P \lor \lnot P \\
\bot \\
\end{array} \\
\lnot P \\
\begin{array} {|l} 
\lnot P \\ \hline
P \lor \lnot P \\
\bot \\
\end{array} \\
\lnot \lnot P \\
\bot \\
\end{array} \\
\lnot \lnot (P \lor \lnot P)
\end{array}
% End Proof
\end{array}$$

Comment: That's an interesting alternative to using the correspondence with Kripke models, thanks!